# Where i can download 32 bit Google Chrome for Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome

I would like to install Chrome on Ubuntu 14.04 32bit, but it's no longer supported.

Comment: You cannot. 32bit is discontinued

Answer (score 0):

If it has to be 32 bit I would recommend  Chromium. Chrome is no longer updated for 32 bit and so security issues and such could be an issue.